# AR.JS custom marker generator returns .patt file with all 0s

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to create an A-Frame/AR.js project that uses custom markers, it works well with marker presets but every time I upload a custom .patt file nothing shows up in front of the camera.

I'm using this [custom marker generator](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html). At first I thought maybe the issue is with the images I'm uploading but then I realized that no matter the image everytime I click 'Download marker' .patt file comes back with all 0s. So my assumption is that something is wrong with the generator itself when (not) picking up uploaded images?

I was wondering if anyone else ran into the same issue / realization and found a way around it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! It only works with `.jpg` images - `.patt` file comes back with all 0s when `.png` images are being uploaded. I hope other folks will find it helpful, too.